# mPDF - Table Footer (tfoot) only appear on last page

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

im trying to add table footer(`<tfoot></tfoot>`) using mPDF to every bottom page (last row).
but it only appear on the last page. I have repeated  but not . Example code below :

**View**

```
  <table>

      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    
      <tbody>
        @foreach($datas as $data)
    
        <tr> 
          <td> $data->name </td>
          <td> $data->position</td>
       </tr>
    
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    
      //i want to this to be on every page
      <tfoot> Footer </foot>
    
 </table>
```

**Controller**

```
 $htmlString = \View::make('test_pdf',['datas'=>$datas]);
 $htmlString =  $htmlString->render();
 $mpdf->SetFooter('Report_Name'  | |{PAGENO}');
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlString);
 return $mpdf->Output('test'.pdf','D');
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: So either create a separate table for each page or use mpdf’s footer feature.

Comment: its data which consist more than 1 page. creating new table will result the same (end of page).
I have try mpdf's footer features but it will overlap with the content from table body.